# Problem with building Nav2 on Ros Humble

Tags: ros-humble, nav2

I try to build nav2_ws from tutorial on [nav2 build and install](https://navigation.ros.org/development_guides/build_docs/index.html#released-distribution-binaries), and I get this error

```
--- stderr: nav_2d_msgs                                              
Error processing idl file: /home/uchi/nav2_ws/build/nav_2d_msgs/rosidl_adapter/nav_2d_msgs/msg/Path2D.idl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uchi/ros2_humble/install/rosidl_generator_py/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_py/rosidl_generator_py", line 40, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/uchi/ros2_humble/install/rosidl_generator_py/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_py/rosidl_generator_py", line 36, in main
    generate_py(args.generator_arguments_file, args.typesupport_impls.split(';'))
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_generator_py/generate_py_impl.py", line 61, in generate_py
    generated_files = generate_files(generator_arguments_file, mapping)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_cmake/__init__.py", line 96, in generate_files
    raise(e)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_cmake/__init__.py", line 87, in generate_files
    expand_template(
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_cmake/__init__.py", line 128, in expand_template
    interpreter = em.Interpreter(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'em' has no attribute 'Interpreter'
gmake[2]: *** [nav_2d_msgs__py/CMakeFiles/nav_2d_msgs__py.dir/build.make:167: rosidl_generator_py/nav_2d_msgs/_nav_2d_msgs_s.ep.rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.c] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:590: nav_2d_msgs__py/CMakeFiles/nav_2d_msgs__py.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< nav_2d_msgs [2.83s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< nav2_msgs [2.24s]
```

It failed on building nav_2d_msgs. Does anyone know how to fix this?

SOLVED: To fix this, I uninstall `em`, which might cause the conflict, and install  `pip install empy & lark`. But it lead to another error  `AttributeError: module 'em' has no attribute "'BUFFERED_OPT'"`. The problem is new empy version doesn't have `BUFFTERD_OPT or RAW_OPT` anymore, from what I understand. I need to install old version of `pip install empy==3.3.4`. Solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77642155/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-raw-opt/77656642#77656642)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't have the EM module installed, that is why the "Interpreter" attribute is not being found.

Try to install it and check if it fix

```
pip3 install empy
```